# Скачивание веб страницы.. Java

Tags: java, html, hashmap

Доброго времени суток всем! Есть такое задание, вот оно:

Имеются две хеш-таблицы. Ключом являются URL. Значением – html-код страницы. Обе таблицы отражают все страницы некоторого заданного множества веб-сайтов. Первая таблица - состояние сайтов на текущий день, а вторая - на предыдущий. Необходимо написать приложение, которое, пользуясь этими таблицами, составило и отправило бы по заданному e-mail письмо следующего формата:

Здравствуйте, Глеб Иванович!
За последние сутки на сайтах произошли следующие изменения: 
1) Исчезли следующие страницы: 
 {список URL-ов} 
2) Появились следующие новые страницы 
 {список URL-ов } 
3) Изменились следующие страницы 
 {список URL-ов }

С "Изменились следующие страницы" понятно что делать, просто сравниваем значения по ключу и все, а вот с "Исчезли следующие страницы" и "Появились следующие страницы" что делать не совсем понимаю. Ну и в принципе как мне получить разные состояния страниц одного URLа (состояние на вчера и на сегодня)?

Comment: Можно просто получить разности множеств ключей обеих таблиц.

Comment: например у нас в первой таблице 5 урлов, во второй 4, соответственно нужно вычислить какой урл отсутствует - это и есть "Исчезли следующие страницы"? Вы это имели ввиду?